# Deriving that center is subset of centralizer(using group actions only)

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-actions

So if we consider our group $N_G(A)$ and let the group act on the set A $\in$ P(G) via conjugation and consider the kernel we will get precisely the kernel being the centralizer, and since the kernel of an action is always a subgroup so the centralizer is a subgroup.

Similarly for the center we act on set G and we get the center. Now is it possible to get that the center is subgroup of the centralizer using only group actions ?

Comment: What is the motivation for this problem? What does it mean to prove something "using only group actions?"

Comment: I mean I know how to do it directly but I just want to see how powerful group actions so I wanted to see if one could prove it only using group actions without relying on proving inclusion.

Comment: Sorry, what's $P(G)$?

Comment: I think what is meant is $A\subseteq G$ (i.e. $A\in \mathscr{P}(G)$). @JoshChen

Comment: yeah exactly @Eoin